# Is it possible to download MQ on windows server?

Tags: ibm-mq

Hello im new on this type of software i had serch on Google about MQ but all what i find is that it can be install on linux windows xp ... 
so this may be stupid but is there any way to install MQ on windows server

Answer (score 3):

> is there any way to install MQ on windows server

Yes. If you have purchased it you should be able to download it for production use via IBM Passport Advantage, all the details can be seen here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24043697

If you only want to use it for personal developer use, you can use the free developer edition, which can be found here:
https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-downloads/

So for clarity, 9.1 is the latest LTS (long term service) release, 9.1.1 is the latest CD (continuous delivery) release. Which is more useful depends on what you are trying to use. It is supported on a range of operating systems, including Windows.

From the 9.1 SOE (System requirements), this is supported in windows server 2016 and windows server 2012r2 (that's the server o/s's as well Windows 10 and 8.1 for desktops). If you need older operating system support, you need to look at older MQ releases, such as 9.0*, 8.0* etc.

Answer (score 0):

MQ windows drivers can be installed on any windows machine, depending upon the system requirement for particular MQ, it is not restricted to Windows XP only

System Requirements for MQ 9.1
https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=B560B760819A11E6B5854315721876AE&osPlatforms=Windows

System Requirements for MQ 9.0
https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=8360DD50895F11E5816C133BBD3A3812&osPlatforms=Windows

System Requirements for MQ 8.0
https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1350550241693&osPlatform=Windows